# Complex Layout returned as PlatformView not showing and behaving correctly

Tags: android, flutter, twilio

I am working on a `Flutter` project with the integration of `Twilio Programmable Video`. The integration happens in the native side.

I have a screen in `Flutter` and in the middle is a space for the `PlatformView` from the native Android (Java). The `PlatformView` returns a complex layout inflated from a layout file so it is not just returning a `VideoView`. Below is my `PlatformView` class:

```
public class RoomViewNative implements PlatformView, MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler {
    private final Context context;
    private final int id;
    final String TAG = "RoomViewNative";
    String accessToken = "";
    String participantId = "";
    String roomId = "";
    RoomViewService roomViewService;
    private final MethodChannel methodChannel;
    View myLayout;
    TextView tv;
    VideoTextureView videoView, videoView2;

    RoomViewNative(@NonNull Context context, int id, @Nullable Map<String, Object> creationParams, BinaryMessenger messenger) {
        this.id = id;
        this.context = context;
        methodChannel = new MethodChannel(messenger, "twilio/room_view_" + id);
        methodChannel.setMethodCallHandler(this);

        accessToken = creationParams.get("accessToken").toString();
        participantId = creationParams.get("participantId").toString();
        roomId = creationParams.get("roomId").toString();

        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        myLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_min, null);


        roomViewService = new RoomViewService(accessToken, participantId, roomId, myLayout, this.context);
        Log.i(TAG, "constructor: " + id);
        roomViewService.init();
        roomViewService.createAudioAndVideoTracks();
        videoView = roomViewService.getVideoView();
        myLayout = roomViewService.getMainLayout();

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView() {
        Log.i(TAG, "getView: " + id);


        if(myLayout == null){
            myLayout = roomViewService.getMainLayout();
        }
//        if(videoView == null) videoView = roomViewService.getVideoView();
//        else return videoView;

//        FrameLayout baseFrameLayout = myLayout.findViewById(R.id.base_framelayout);
//        baseFrameLayout.addView(videoView);

//        LinearLayout layoutPrimaryVideo1 = myLayout.findViewById(R.id.layoutPrimaryVideo1);
//        layoutPrimaryVideo1.addView(videoView);

//        LinearLayout layoutPrimaryVideo2 = myLayout.findViewById(R.id.layoutPrimaryVideo2);
//        layoutPrimaryVideo2.addView(videoView2);

        return  myLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {}

    @Override
    public void onMethodCall(@NonNull MethodCall call, @NonNull MethodChannel.Result result) {
        switch (call.method) {
            case "init":
                init();
                break;
            case "endCall":
                roomViewService.disconnect();
                break;
            case "disableMic":
                roomViewService.muteClickListener(false);
                break;
            case "enableMic":
                roomViewService.muteClickListener(true);
                break;
            default:
                result.notImplemented();
        }
    }

    private void init() {
        //roomViewService.init();

    }
}
```

When I run the app, it always say about something like `video view not initialized or already release`. This is when I reference and use the `VideoView` inside my layout.

What is more interesting is that, when I dynamically create the `VideoView` in the `getView()` method, it is displaying correctly. But the problem is that I needed to add more VideoViews in the layout for multiple participants that are joining. When I try to add more views, the video feed stops working and the extra views are not added (shown).

I am using a class `RoomViewService` to create and connect to the room and handle the participants and the layout. The method `getVideoView` has the same exact process in displaying the `localVideoTrack` in the `VideoView` inside the layout, this one just returns a `VideoView`.

I just don't know if this is a known issue in Flutter > PlatformView. Before this, I also ran into problem like 1 view is only visible and returned from a layout with so many views. The root layout is a `CoordinatorLayout` and when I changed it to `LinearLayout`, the views are appearing already.

Comment: did you find any solutions, we're facing similar issue using opentok sdk